# CiviGroup Roles Sync errors

Tags: drupal, groups

After upgrading Drupal to 7.3.8 (don't know if this is related), I'm getting an error when a user logs on and belongs to groups/holds a role that is set up with CiviGroup Roles Sync.

> Role *groupname* (*group id*) should be held by user *username* (*drupal user id*)
>   because they are part of *group id* (contactID: *civi id*)

When I check the user's groups and roles, they appear to be correct.
The error is listed in dblog for each group that they are a member of.

Groups are regular groups, not smart groups.

Appears to be happening for all users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is actually an 'error', the status is just misleading.

The Group <> Role sync runs on a user when they log in, syncing up the roles. All this message is saying is: "When the user logged in, I added role x, because they are a member of group y."

The severity of these database log messages is misleading and will be fixed up in 4.7 by this commit: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/pull/272